# Incremental crawl - ChangedIdEnumerator not executed

Tags: crawl-external-content

I have a BCS model (SharePoint 2010) that implement incremental crawl with `ChangedIdEnumerator`.

My model service implements three methods (`ReadItem` [`SpecificFinder`], `ReadList`[`Finder`] and `ReadChangedList`[`ChangedIdEnumerator`]).

The `ReadList`[`Finder`] is marked with the property **Rootfinder**, in order to the crawl use it in full indexing.

The full crawl works, but the incremental crawl, that should execute the `ReadChangedList` is not called, instead the the `ReadList` is called again and a full indexing is performed.

I haven't found a working example for this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm the same problem... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to use the `ChangedIdEnumerator` and `DeletedIdEnumerator` with a `DotNetAssembly`. From personal experience (and exasperation), they do not seem to allow the `SpecificFinder` and `StreamAccessor` to be invoked with a Custom assembly.

I have implemented a couple of `<IdEnumerator, ChangedIdEnumerator, DeletedIdEnumerator, SpecificFinder, StreamAccessor>` assemblies and the Changed/Deleted collections do *not* result in calls to the `SpecificFinder` in Custom assemblies.

Microsoft has been mute on this point.
I do hope this helps.